# Android ExoPlayer - How to add points of interest and their callbacks?

Tags: android, events, callback, exoplayer

I've been successfully using ExoPlayer to play audio in my app.

I have a list of points in time (in milliseconds) in which I would like ExoPlayer to raise an event whenever it passes through them during playback. I can't find anything looking at the source code on GitHub that can give me a clue on how I can do that.

Can someone point me to the right direction/give me any ideas?

Comment: Are you taking about playback time which shows on seekbar ?

Comment: Use CounterDownTimer check after each tick for your event.

Comment: @NilayDani Yes.

Comment: @Qamar I don't want a pull solution. I want a push solution. I pull solution will always have an error and will depend on the window I set to pull.

Comment: @Override
  public int getDuration() {
    return exoPlayer.getDuration() == ExoPlayer.UNKNOWN_TIME ? 0
        : (int) exoPlayer.getDuration();
  }

Comment: @Override
  public void seekTo(int timeMillis) {
    long seekPosition = exoPlayer.getDuration() == ExoPlayer.UNKNOWN_TIME ? 0
        : Math.min(Math.max(0, timeMillis), getDuration());
    exoPlayer.seekTo(seekPosition);
  }

Comment: Is that what you want ?

Comment: @NilayDani No, I want to detect when the playback passes through a certain instant in time I especify. I don't want to seekTo.

Comment: Ohh That you can set it by yourself by creating a new interface when seekTo returns the certain value you can call that event in your code.

Comment: @NilayDani Please explain further. seekTo is NOT what I want. I don't want to explicitly go to a certain time, I want to KNOW when a certain time has been hit. That's all.

Comment: @Tiago Yes, I got your point I am telling you the same. Just put a callback inside seekTo Method that when certain value is returned that callback fires an event and you can do your required tasks based on that .

Comment: Customize TextTrackRenderer. Refer you here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30994242/how-to-show-subtitle-in-android-exoplayer

Comment: Put empty subtitle with your time events and listen them in custom TrackRenderer

Comment: @NilayDani Are you suggesting I download ExoPlayer's source code and add the callback code there? I don't see another way of "adding a callback to the seekTo method". Currently I import ExoPlayer as a simple compile statement in build.gradle.