# How to add Subtitles(.SRT files) to video in Exoplayer android?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer

i am working on a project where i should play .srt files along with video in android. I was working through the samples of Exoplayer but cant able to play .srt files with video.

The code i used is,

```
MediaSource mediaSource = new HlsMediaSource(Uri.parse("https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8"),
                mediaDataSourceFactory, mainHandler, null);

         Format textFormat = Format.createTextSampleFormat(null, MimeTypes.APPLICATION_SUBRIP,
                null, Format.NO_VALUE, Format.NO_VALUE, "en", null);

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.storiesinflight.com/js_videosub/jellies.srt");


        MediaSource subtitleSource = new SingleSampleMediaSource(uri, mediaDataSourceFactory, textFormat, C.TIME_UNSET);
// Plays the video with the sideloaded subtitle.
        MergingMediaSource mergedSource =
                new MergingMediaSource(mediaSource, subtitleSource);

        player.prepare(mergedSource);
```

Can anyone please suggest me solution for this or any tutorial links for the same. Your help is very much appreciated !

Comment: You need to use SubtitleView with TextRenderer to setup it correctly  (hope you are using ExoPlayer 2)

Comment: @dari  yes dario, i am using Exoplayer 2. My sample has Subtitleview and TextRenderer too. Still i am facing issue. Can u please suggest me a tutorial for this?





Code for subtitle view in my sample,

       subtitleLayout = (SubtitleView) findViewById(com.google.android.exoplayer2.R.id.subtitles);
        subtitleLayout.setUserDefaultStyle();
        subtitleLayout.setUserDefaultTextSize();

Comment: If you found the answer kindly update. None of the below things are working for me.

Comment: @VikasAcharya check below Snippet Code

Answer (score 4):

I just edit exoplayer example in there Player activity such like... and its working for me...

```
 private void initializePlayer() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (player == null) {
            boolean preferExtensionDecoders = intent.getBooleanExtra(PREFER_EXTENSION_DECODERS, false);
            UUID drmSchemeUuid = intent.hasExtra(DRM_SCHEME_UUID_EXTRA)
                    ? UUID.fromString(intent.getStringExtra(DRM_SCHEME_UUID_EXTRA)) : null;
            DrmSessionManager<FrameworkMediaCrypto> drmSessionManager = null;
            if (drmSchemeUuid != null) {
                String drmLicenseUrl = intent.getStringExtra(DRM_LICENSE_URL);
                String[] keyRequestPropertiesArray = intent.getStringArrayExtra(DRM_KEY_REQUEST_PROPERTIES);
                Map<String, String> keyRequestProperties;
                if (keyRequestPropertiesArray == null || keyRequestPropertiesArray.length < 2) {
                    keyRequestProperties = null;
                } else {
                    keyRequestProperties = new HashMap<>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < keyRequestPropertiesArray.length - 1; i += 2) {
                        keyRequestProperties.put(keyRequestPropertiesArray[i],
                                keyRequestPropertiesArray[i + 1]);
                    }
                }
                try {
                    drmSessionManager = buildDrmSessionManager(drmSchemeUuid, drmLicenseUrl,
                            keyRequestProperties);
                } catch (UnsupportedDrmException e) {
                    int errorStringId = Util.SDK_INT < 18 ? R.string.error_drm_not_supported
                            : (e.reason == UnsupportedDrmException.REASON_UNSUPPORTED_SCHEME
                            ? R.string.error_drm_unsupported_scheme : R.string.error_drm_unknown);
                    showToast(errorStringId);
                    return;
                }
            }

            @SimpleExoPlayer.ExtensionRendererMode int extensionRendererMode =
                    ((AppController) getApplication()).useExtensionRenderers()
                            ? (preferExtensionDecoders ? SimpleExoPlayer.EXTENSION_RENDERER_MODE_PREFER
                            : SimpleExoPlayer.EXTENSION_RENDERER_MODE_ON)
                            : SimpleExoPlayer.EXTENSION_RENDERER_MODE_OFF;
            TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory =
                    new AdaptiveVideoTrackSelection.Factory(BANDWIDTH_METER);
            trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
            trackSelectionHelper = new TrackSelectionHelper(trackSelector, videoTrackSelectionFactory);
            player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector, new DefaultLoadControl(),
                    drmSessionManager, extensionRendererMode);
            player.addListener(this);

            eventLogger = new EventLogger(trackSelector);
            player.addListener(eventLogger);
            player.setAudioDebugListener(eventLogger);
            player.setVideoDebugListener(eventLogger);
            player.setMetadataOutput(eventLogger);

            simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
            player.setPlayWhenReady(shouldAutoPlay);
            debugViewHelper = new DebugTextViewHelper(player, debugTextView);
            debugViewHelper.start();
            playerNeedsSource = true;


        }
        if (playerNeedsSource) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            Log.d("URL action: ", action);
            Uri[] uris;
            String[] extensions;
            if (ACTION_VIEW.equals(action)) {
                uris = new Uri[] {intent.getData()};
                extensions = new String[] {intent.getStringExtra(EXTENSION_EXTRA)};
            } else if (ACTION_VIEW_LIST.equals(action)) {
                String[] uriStrings = intent.getStringArrayExtra(URI_LIST_EXTRA);
                uris = new Uri[uriStrings.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < uriStrings.length; i++) {
                    uris[i] = Uri.parse(uriStrings[i]);
                    Log.d("URL action2: ", String.valueOf(uris[i])+" ");
                }
                extensions = intent.getStringArrayExtra(EXTENSION_LIST_EXTRA);
                if (extensions == null) {
                    extensions = new String[uriStrings.length];
                }
            } else {
                showToast(getString(R.string.unexpected_intent_action, action));
                return;
            }
            if (Util.maybeRequestReadExternalStoragePermission(this, uris)) {
                // The player will be reinitialized if the permission is granted.
                return;
            }
            MediaSource[] mediaSources = new MediaSource[uris.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < uris.length; i++) {
                mediaSources[i] = buildMediaSource(uris[i], extensions[i]);
                Log.d("URL action extensions: ", String.valueOf( extensions[i]));
            }
            MediaSource mediaSource = mediaSources.length == 1 ? mediaSources[0]
                    : new ConcatenatingMediaSource(mediaSources);
            boolean haveResumePosition = resumeWindow != C.INDEX_UNSET;
            if (haveResumePosition) {
                player.seekTo(resumeWindow, resumePosition);
            }
            // edit for subtitle
           // player.prepare(mediaSource, !haveResumePosition, false);
         //   playerNeedsSource = false;
          // player.seekTo(0);
            //updateButtonVisibilities();

           /* MediaSource mediaSource = new HlsMediaSource(Uri.parse("https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8"),
                    mediaDataSourceFactory, mainHandler, null);*/

            Format textFormat = Format.createTextSampleFormat(null, MimeTypes.APPLICATION_SUBRIP,
                    null, Format.NO_VALUE, Format.NO_VALUE, "en", null);

            Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.storiesinflight.com/js_videosub/jellies.srt");


            MediaSource subtitleSource = new SingleSampleMediaSource(uri, mediaDataSourceFactory, textFormat, C.TIME_UNSET);
// Plays the video with the sideloaded subtitle.
            MergingMediaSource mergedSource =
                    new MergingMediaSource(mediaSource, subtitleSource);

            player.prepare(mergedSource,!haveResumePosition, false);
            playerNeedsSource = false;
            //player.seekTo(0);
        }


    }
```

Comment: no explanation at all and didn't find `mediaDataSourceFactory` in this answer

Answer (score 4):

I know it's too late to answer this question, but if someone else falls for it, try this :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
SimpleExoPlayerView exoPlayerView;
SimpleExoPlayer exoPlayer;
String videoURL = "http://blueappsoftware.in/layout_design_android_blog.mp4";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    exoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.exo_player_view);
    try {


        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter));
        exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);

        Uri videoURI = Uri.parse(videoURL);
        Uri subtitleUri=Uri.parse("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/findandfix-2f4a9.appspot.com/o/Despacito%20Remix%20Luis%20Fonsi%20ft.Daddy%20Yankee%20Justin%20Bieber%20Lyrics%20%5BSpanish%5D.srt?alt=media&token=63344d04-af1c-4e2c-9d15-381bf7159308");
        DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer_video");

        ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
        MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(videoURI, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);

        // Build the subtitle MediaSource.
        Format subtitleFormat = Format.createTextSampleFormat(
                null, // An identifier for the track. May be null.
                MimeTypes.APPLICATION_SUBRIP, // The mime type. Must be set correctly.
                null,
                Format.NO_VALUE,
                Format.NO_VALUE,
                "en",
                null); // The subtitle language. May be null.

        MediaSource subtitleSource =new SingleSampleMediaSource(subtitleUri, dataSourceFactory, subtitleFormat, C.TIME_UNSET);

        MergingMediaSource mergedSource =
                new MergingMediaSource(mediaSource, subtitleSource);

        exoPlayerView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);
        exoPlayer.prepare(mergedSource);
        exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("MainAcvtivity"," exoplayer error "+ e.toString());
    }

}
```

}

Comment: it says , can not resolve method createTextSampleFormat()

Comment: SingleSampleMediaSource is deprecated what do I use

Comment: @PembaTamang You can use SingleSampleMediaSource.Factory methods

Comment: @solidfox New Exoplayer release removed all `create` method from `Format` class. You can set all required format fields with `MediaItem.SubtitleConfiguration.Builder`.

Answer (score 3):

```
SubtitleView subtitleView=(SubtitleView)findViewById(com.google.android.exoplayer2.R.id.exo_subtitles); 
player.setTextOutput(new ComponentListener());

public class ComponentListener implements TextRenderer.Output{
  @Override
  public void onCues(List<Cue> cues) {
    if (subtitleView != null) {
        subtitleView.onCues(cues);
    }
  }
```

}

To show/hide the subtitleView:

```
subtitleView.setVisiblity(Visible/Gone);
```

Comment: i like your answer, but how to do i add an external .srt subtitle for the player to sync with the playback.

Comment: can anyone explain where is the subtitle path here ?

Comment: The subtitle is embedded within the m3u8 or mpd file.

Comment: Can we update this for kotlin and latest library, this does not work

Answer (score 3):

USE Below Code to enable Subtitle

```
private void playWithCaption() {

        MediaItem.SubtitleConfiguration subtitle =
                new MediaItem.SubtitleConfiguration.Builder(subtitleUri)
                        .setMimeType(MimeTypes.APPLICATION_SUBRIP) // The correct MIME type (required).
                        .setLanguage("en") // MUST, The subtitle language (optional).
                        .setSelectionFlags(C.SELECTION_FLAG_DEFAULT) //MUST,  Selection flags for the track (optional).
                        .build();
        MediaItem mediaItem =
                new MediaItem.Builder()
                        .setUri(videoUri)
                        .setSubtitleConfigurations(ImmutableList.of(subtitle))
                        .build();

        player.setMediaItem(mediaItem);

        player.prepare();;


        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);

    }
```

use below Dependancy

```
implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.17.1"
implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.17.1"
implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.17.1"
```

Comment: Thank you! The documentation said the Language and selection flags were optional, but without them, subtitles did not work for me. Now they do!

Answer (score 2):

I have given a lots of efforts for this and finally concluded to the solution...

Sharing here for the reference

Srt file format ref link - http://www.storiesinflight.com/js_videosub/jellies.srt

Solution which finds a way for me - https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/3869#issuecomment-367067013

Adding Exoplayer code here

```
// initialize exoplayer
private void initializeExoPlayer() {
    if (player == null) {
        video_view = (PlayerView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);

        // 1. Create a default TrackSelector
        LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl(
                new DefaultAllocator(true, 16),
                VideoPlayerConfig.MIN_BUFFER_DURATION,
                VideoPlayerConfig.MAX_BUFFER_DURATION,
                VideoPlayerConfig.MIN_PLAYBACK_START_BUFFER,
                VideoPlayerConfig.MIN_PLAYBACK_RESUME_BUFFER, -1, true);

        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory =
                new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
        TrackSelector trackSelector =
                new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
        // 2. Create the player
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(new DefaultRenderersFactory(mContext), trackSelector, loadControl);
        video_view.setPlayer(player);

    }
}
```

```
public void buildMediaSource(String videoUrl, final String questionVideoThumbnail) {


    Uri mUri = Uri.parse(videoUrl);
    Uri srtUri = Uri.parse("http://www.storiesinflight.com/js_videosub/jellies.srt");

    // Measures bandwidth during playback. Can be null if not required.
    DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    // Produces DataSource instances through which media data is loaded.
    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(mContext,
            Util.getUserAgent(mContext, getString(R.string.app_name)), bandwidthMeter);
    // This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played.
    MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(mUri);
    // Prepare the player with the source.

    Format textFormat = Format.createTextSampleFormat(null, MimeTypes.APPLICATION_SUBRIP,
            null, Format.NO_VALUE, Format.NO_VALUE, "en", null, Format.OFFSET_SAMPLE_RELATIVE);
    MediaSource textMediaSource = new SingleSampleMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(srtUri, textFormat, C.TIME_UNSET);
    MergingMediaSource mediaSource = new MergingMediaSource(videoSource, textMediaSource);

    player.prepare(mediaSource);
    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    player.addListener(this);


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the merged media source I created a Listener for the Text Rendered as an Interface as in the Demo

```
    private final class ComponentListener implements TextRenderer.Output{

        @Override
        public void onCues(List<Cue> cues) {
            if (subtitleView != null) {
                subtitleView.onCues(cues);
            }
        }
    }

player.setTextOutput(componentListener);
```

I created an object and set the TextOutput as this

Answer (score 0):

```
 PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getContext(), v);
                popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.subtile_menu, popup.getMenu());
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(item -> {
                    if (item.getItemId()==R.id.remove_subtitle){
                        //player.prepare(videoSource);
                        player.prepare(videoSource, false, false);
                    }else if (item.getItemId()==R.id.english){
                        if (caption){
                            Format textFormat = Format.createTextSampleFormat(null, MimeTypes.APPLICATION_SUBRIP,
                                    null, Format.NO_VALUE, Format.NO_VALUE, "en", null, Format.OFFSET_SAMPLE_RELATIVE);
                            MediaSource textMediaSource = new SingleSampleMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                                    .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(sub_url), textFormat, C.TIME_UNSET);
                            MergingMediaSource mediaSource = new MergingMediaSource(videoSource, textMediaSource);
                            player.prepare(mediaSource, false, false);
                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Subtitle not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                });
                popup.show();
```